# Pointer to member function of derived class, but not derived(virtual) function

Tags: c++, inheritance, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I have a particular problem I want to solve, I'm not sure if it's possible as I can't find any information or examples of it being done.
Basically, I have:

```
class ParentObject {};

class DerivedObject : public ParentObject
{
    void myFunction(){}
};

class OtherDerivedObject : public ParentObject
{
   void myOtherFunction(){}
};
```

and want a function pointer to ParentObject::* and have it able to take functions from either derived class. 
My reason for wanting to do so, I have another class

```
class functionRegistry
{
  std::map<string, *functionPoint> functionMap;
}
```

and each object (ideally in ParentObject but can do individually in the derived objects if necessary) have an instance of a functionRegistry, and I need functionPoint to be able to point to functions in objects of either type DerivedObject or OtherDerivedObject.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like [a classic XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: could you elaborate more in particular what is your use case?

Comment: Ok I have a solution now(below) but for interest's sake: I am writing a game engine using component-entity based architecture, where the  components talk to each other through simple messages. Messages consist of things like FORCE_X+50, where I will parse the message into: the first half which will correlate to a function and the second which will be an argument.. I figure this way it creates a flexible environment for me to easily add functionality where I need it. Different components will take different messages and do different things.

Comment: For example the physics component will take  FORCE_Y-10 messages(or a vector force etc), the graphics would take things like ANIMSPEED_-1 or ANIMCHANGE_JUMP.  Seems like a better way to do it than endless hard-coded if statements or something.

Comment: Obviously all those functions would have the same signature, right? so why not simply store ``std::function<void(void)> (or whatever signature your functions have) instances into your registry. It should also work for pointer to member type of functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is a `static_cast` to populate the map with the correct type.

```
using pfunc_type = void (ParentObject::*)() ;
pfunc_type pfunc1 = static_cast<pfunc_type>(&DerivedObject::myFunction);
```

As this is allowed by the standard:

**[expr.static.cast/12] - [§5.2.9¶12](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#12)**

> A prvalue of type “pointer to member of D of type cv1 T” can be
>   converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to member of B of type cv2 T”,
>   where B is a base class (Clause [class.derived]) of D, if cv2 is the
>   same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1.72 If
>   no valid standard conversion from “pointer to member of B of type T”
>   to “pointer to member of D of type T” exists ([conv.mem]), the program
>   is ill-formed. The null member pointer value ([conv.mem]) is converted
>   to the null member pointer value of the destination type. If class B
>   contains the original member, or is a base or derived class of the
>   class containing the original member, the resulting pointer to member
>   points to the original member. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined. [
>   **Note: although class B need not contain the original member, the
>   dynamic type of the object with which indirection through the pointer
>   to member is performed must contain the original member;** see
>   [expr.mptr.oper].  — end note ]

But while this is allowed, you must be *very* careful to make sure you apply the pointer to member on an object with the correct dynamic type.

Comment: Why behavior is undefined? Why it cannot be a compilation error?

Comment: @Mikhail - Assume a function that accepts a pointer a member function of a base class, and a pointer to a base class object. How would you check at compile time this constraint holds?

Comment: @StoryTeller Sorry, are you sure you did not make any typo in this question? You have base class for both pointer to member function and pointer to object.

Comment: @Mikhail - No mistake, I meant for [something like this](http://ideone.com/yNSqlS). How can you check statically that an arbitrary member function exists in an arbitrary sub-class? I don't think it's possible for every case with growing program complexity. Leaving it UB is the best option the standard has IMO. Very little checking but great flexibility if used correctly.

Comment: @Chrysm_Seal since the answer was "Excellent", why didn't you accept it? :)